# How can Google Drive export files in deeply-nested folders?

Tags: google-drive, export

I have an archive of images for our project.  The images are well-organized in deeply-nested folders.

The client is behind an elaborate firewall, and cannot access any Google Drive link.

I need to export the files to zip, so that we can put the link on our site, or email them the archive.

---

How can I do this export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive *does* export sub-folders, but only when they have content.

Simply find the folder you want to export in the left-hand sidebar, click the down arrow next to it, and select *Download*:

[image]

There *is* a 2GB limit, so if the sum of filesizes in your folder tree exceeds that, you may run into trouble.

If that is a problem, another solution is to set up synchronization with your computer. Then you'll have a copy of the entire Google Drive on your hard drive, and you are free to create a zip file from any folder you'd like, from your computer.

See [Overview of Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424384?hl=en&ref_topic=14942&rd=1) for help installing the Google Drive client on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  per the question, the client is behind a firewall that blocks all access to google-drive related domains.  Sync is not possible

Comment: I do not understand how your solution works: you say to right-click to download ***each*** folder?  There are dozens at the top level, and if they each flatten their contents, then they are still not useful

Comment: No, not _each_ folder, but each _top level_ folder. If you want to export your _entire_ Google Drive, this will not work. The zip file which results in an export of a folder retains the folder structure.
You can also use Google Takeout (https://www.google.com/settings/takeout), which also allows you to export the _entire_ contents of your Google Drive.

Comment: As for the sync suggestion, I meant that _you_ set up Google Drive sync, so that you have a copy of your Google Drive on your computer. From your computer, you could easily create a zip file using any Zip software.

Comment: I don't need the entire content.  My drive has 15-30 top-level folders.  One of those i need to export, with all of it's deep nesting. You seem to be saying that I need to export the folders inside that top-level folder (in order to retain the structure).  I don't understand why exporting 2nd level folders will retain deeply-nested structure when then 1st level folder export does not.

Comment: No. So you want to export _one_ of your top level folders, with all its subfolders, and get a zip file with the same folder structure. If so, right-click on the top-level folder you want to export, select _Download_, and you're good to go.

Comment: I did try that.  It exports flat - and thus I opened a question here

Comment: OK, that's weird. I get a zip file with the complete folder tree.